# MVC 4 WebApi URI of correlation object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

New to Web API and looking for help.

I have an object "Bar" that has a List

I want to POST beers to that Bar.  (ultimately it will fill in a correlation table on my DB)

1. What controller should handle that POST?
2. What do I put in the HttpResponseMessage because there aren't any GET methods to map to?

thanks

tal

Comment: If you're new to REST as well, have a look at this document: http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web API is not an opinionated framework.  You can do it however makes the most sense to you.  Personally I would create a BarBeersController and post to that.  You can put a 201 in the response message.  You don't need a body if you don't want.

Comment: Would you then create dummy get statement to retrieve that record?  I was reading that the POST is supposed to have a URI to the corresponding GET. The DTO has no value other than as part of an insert.  I am building a BearBar Object, but ultimately I feel like this should be a PUT on the bar object passing in the entire bar object.

Comment: @TalMcMahon There is no requirement that a resource that supports POST must also support a GET. However, it seems reasonable to create resource that returns a list of beers served by a bar.  But that's your design choice.  You could do PUT, however, it could become a pretty big representation at that point.  It may not feel very efficient later on when you want to add one beer to a bar and you have to send the entire list.